# junit theories doesn't work with maven

Tags: maven, junit, theory

For some reason, my test class works and passes in eclipse, but if i try from the command line using `mvn test -Dtest=BmwTest` it fails. The reason it's giving is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Never found parameters that satisfied method assumptions.  Violated assumptions: []
```

My code:

```java
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class BmwTest {

    @DataPoints
    public static Integer[] a = { 
             1,
             2,
             3
    };

    @Theory
    public void testMyTest(Integer a) {

    }

}
```

I've tried using primitives (`int`), and it still gives the same error. The singular annotation `@DataPoint` works, but the plural annotation `@DataPoints` doesn't. What's going on? Much help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine through Eclipse and Maven. I'm using Maven 3 with JUnit 4.9. What Maven and JUnit versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i did some digging around, and it turns out that junit-dep was causing the problem.  i checked the test classpath, and both junit.jar and junit-dep.jar were being included.  basically, they're the same, the only difference being junit-dep.jar doesn't include the hamcrest libs.  in case you're wondering where junit-dep came from, it's a dependency for jmock, which i forgot to mention we're using.  i removed the junit-dep dependency in my pom, and everything worked.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```